# Pass ID on onClick Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am trying to pass the email using the onClick function and I want to show that email in alert:

```
<td>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" name="buton" onclick="myfunction(<?php  $email;   ?>)" >Edit</button>
</td>
```

Here is my function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction(id)
    {
        alert(id);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: also shouldn't it be `echo $email`

Comment: So what's the problem here? Do you encouter any error?

Comment: Also, $email is probably a string. You'll need to print it between quotes. myfunction('<?php  echo $email;   ?>');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to make two changes to validate your code :

1. You should add `echo` to pass the php variable to JS.
2. You need to add **single** quotes since the `$email` is a string and you've already using double quotes in `onclick` attribute.

   ```
   <td>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" name="buton" onclick="myfunction('<?php echo $email; ?>')" >Edit</button>
   </td>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myfunction(id)
    {
        alert(id);
    }
```

```html
<td>
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="buton" onClick="myfunction('<?php echo $email;   ?>')" >Edit</button></td>
```

You need to put the email in 'single quotes'

Comment: The issue was at the single quotes, thats why I kept it simple with a hardcoded email. But I changed it now!

Answer (score 0):

try this 
when you are passing the email(String) it should be in `quote` and while using php in javascript in this case u have to use `echo`

```
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" name="buton" onclick="myfunction('<?php  echo $email;   ?>')" >Edit</button></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably the PHP tag `<?=` that echoes the $email variable as an argument to the JavaScript function. Note that you will need quotation marks for the email:

`onclick='myfunction("<?= $email ?>")'`

If shorttags are not enabled the long version must be used:

`onclick='myfunction("<?php echo $email; ?>")'`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, you are just not echoing the value of `$email` in a good way:
- Lack of the single quotes in `myfunction(' … ')`
- Lack of `echo` inside your php tags `myfunction('<?php echo $email ?>')`

To avoid that kind of problems…
In your php, I suggest you to use heredoc syntax:

```
echo <<< EOD
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" name="buton" onclick="myfunction('{$email}')">Edit</button></td>
EOD;
```

Note the `{ }` around the variable. They are not necessary, but I suggest you to use them, as they make the variables more noticable.

⋅ ⋅ ⋅

The result will be:

```js
function myfunction(id) {
  alert(id);
}
```

```html
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" name="buton" onclick="myfunction('myemail@stackoverflow.com')">Edit</button></td>
```

Documentation about Heredoc syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

echo the variable in the php tag

```
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" name="buton" onclick="myfunction('<?php  echo $email;   ?>')" >Edit</button></td>
```